# What is the [dnd-miniatures] tag for, and can we give it a tag wiki / revise its usage?

Tags: discussion, support, status-completed, tags, tag-wiki

We have a [dnd-miniatures](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dnd-miniatures) tag on main site which has 8 questions and no tag wiki, and I'm not sure what to add for one, nor what this tag gets used for exactly.

- There seems to be a [D&D Miniatures game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dungeons_%26_Dragons_Miniatures_Game) that was [unrelated to other D&D games](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/94/what-is-the-difference-between-dd-and-dd-miniatures), but it was discontinuned in 2011
- Wizards of the Coast also sells [D&D-branded miniatures](http://dnd.wizards.com/products/tabletop-games/miniatures) which I *think* don't have any accessory game, and are just intended for use in D&D 5e, but I'm out of the loop on this stuff.
- It also gets used for things which I think are disconnected from those entirely, such as questions just asking about miniatures for D&D. These might be better off using [miniatures](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/miniatures) or some other tag.

What's this tag actually for? How should we wiki-ify it, and how should we revise its usage if necessary?

Answer (score 3):

Here's what I think is the case. Questions using this tag are covering one of these categories:

Questions about the D&D miniatures game, and we should rename the tag to [dnd-miniatures-game](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dnd-miniatures-game) to make it clearer:

- [What does the symbol on the bottom of a WotC miniature mean?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/4971/what-does-the-symbol-on-the-bottom-of-a-wotc-miniature-mean)
- [Pre-painted Miniatures for D&D other than from Wizards](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/8174/pre-painted-miniatures-for-dd-other-than-from-wizards) (also probably a [game-recommendation](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-recommendation) that we'd close)
- [What is the difference between D&D and D&D Miniatures?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/94/what-is-the-difference-between-dd-and-dd-miniatures)
- [Are stats from D&D Miniatures compatible with D&D 4e?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/55298/are-stats-from-dd-miniatures-compatible-with-dd-4e) [duplicate]
- [Are D&D Miniatures compatible with D&D HeroScape?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/1959/are-dd-miniatures-compatible-with-dd-heroscape) seems to be comparing the D&D Miniatures game to [Heroscape](http://heroscape.wikia.com/wiki/Heroscape), and I'm not sure what that is.

Totally unrelated, should just have the tag dropped:

- [Configurations for D&D dungeon tiles?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/14780/configurations-for-dd-dungeon-tiles)

Actually just [miniatures](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/miniatures), I think:

- [What is a good way to get a large range of fantasy miniatures?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/19681/what-is-a-good-way-to-get-a-large-range-of-fantasy-miniatures) [closed]
- [Good Miniature for a Dancing Weapon](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/35504/good-miniature-for-a-dancing-weapon) (also, a [game-recommendation](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-recommendation) again)

Comment: Originally was for *D&D Miniatures*, yes. This looks like an accurate assessment, and I agree adding `-game` to it would be helpful.

Comment: I've actioned this post. [dnd-miniatures] has been renamed to [dnd-miniatures-game] and the other three posts have had the tag removed. @SevenSidedDie Thanks for helping clarify & confirm.